# how does tokio::select! match multiple branches?

Tags: rust, macros

I'm reading the macro definition:

```
( $p:pat = $($t:tt)* ) => {
        // Randomly generate a starting point. This makes `select!` a bit more
        // fair and avoids always polling the first future.
        $crate::select!(@{ start={ $crate::macros::support::thread_rng_n(BRANCHES) }; () } $p = $($t)*)
    };
```

It seems to me it's only matching a single pattern, how does it match multiple patterns?

IMO to match multiple patterns, it should be `$($p:pat = $($t:tt))*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it matches multiple. It captures the first pattern and `=`, and everything afterwards as `tt`s. "Everything afterwards" includes other patterns and their associated bodies. They are later handled by other arms.

Comment: what exactly does `tt` match?

Comment: @mathematicanewbie [Any single token tree](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/macros-by-example.html#metavariables).

Comment: can you briefly explain how this macro actually expands every branch, what does BRANCHES mean here?

Comment: @mathematicanewbie This is another question, and can be appropriate to a new SO question.

Comment: Let me confirm the case where there's only 1 branch, say `Some(service_request) = self.discv5_recv.recv() => {}`, here `$($t:tt)*` will match `self.discv5_recv.recv()`, `=>`, `{}` respectively, right?

Comment: @mathematicanewbie Yes. And on multiple, e.g. `Some(a) = b => {} c = d => {}` it'll match `b => {} c = d => {}`.

Comment: It would be great if you can explain the magic happening here.

Comment: @mathematicanewbie What magic? I don't understand.

Comment: How this macro expands all branches . I don't understand how it actually works.

Comment: @mathematicanewbie As a said, this is a new question and should be a in a new SO question.